# CakePHP Save data in HABTM Table

Tags: cakephp, save, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to save an array like this

```
$myData = array(
    'User' => array('id' => 17),
    'Group' => array(
        array('group_id' => 2),
        array('group_id' => 3),
        array('group_id' => 4),
        array('group_id' => 5),
        array('group_id' => 6)
    )
);
```

In my HABTM join table (groups_users). I tried the following *save* calls, but **none** of them worked.

```
$this->User->save($myData);
$this->User->saveAssociated($myData);
$this->User->saveAll($myData);
$this->User->GroupsUsers->save($myData);
$this->User->GroupsUsers->saveAll($myData);
```

Before you ask: **Yes**, my associations are set-up correctly and I was able to save data by calling:

```
$this->User->GroupsUsers->saveAll(array(
    0 => array(
        'GroupsUsers' => array('user_id' => $id, 'group_id' => 1)
    ),
    1 => array(
        'GroupsUsers' => array('user_id' => $id, 'group_id' => 2)
    )
));
```

**BUT only one of both records are saved, although I set *unique* to false in the model's HABTM relationship definition.**

Where is the error? Is the structure of my array invalid?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data array is incorrectly formatted.

Your `Group` model will probably have an `id` field, and your join model `GroupsUser` will have a `group_id` field.

So you need to change your `group_id` to `id`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$myData = array(
    'User' => array('id' => 17),
    'Group' => array(
        'Group' => array(
            0 => 2,
            1 => 3,
            2 => 4,
            3 => 5,
            4 => 6
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: On which model should I perform the save call?

Comment: the user model. $this->User->saveAll($myData);

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your question even if it's old.

**You doesn't have to call your 'GroupsUsers' model in your saveAll call**, this is precisely the goal of associating Models, cakePHP does that for you.

You should pass this array to a saveAll function on your User/Group model:

```
array{
    array{
        'User' => array {
             'id' => 25
         },
         'Group' => array {
             'id' => 2
         }
    }
    array{
        'User' => array {
             'id' => 47
         },
         'Group' => array {
             'id' => 2
         }
    }
}
```

Both your User and Group Models should have and HABTM relation with each other, so that you just have to do that:

From the User/Group controller:

```
$this->User/Group->SaveAll($myData);
```

From the User/Group Model:

```
$this->SaveAll($myData);
```

And that's it, the GroupsUsers table will save 2 records, by saving by yourself in the HABTM relation table, you are not using the power of cakePHP.

And the records in both User and Group tables will be created if the ID doesn't exist, updated if not.

**The only reason to save in an HABTM table** is if you have some extra information you want to save in this table such as a 'validated' fields if you want to validate a member after he asked to join a group for example.